# Error ejecutando codigo sencillo JSP

Tags: jsp, eclipse

Resulta que estoy iniciando en esto del JSP, y siguiendo un tutorial de youtube, pues sencillamente no me va este codigo, quito específicamente "<%= new java.util.date() %>" y va todo normal, no se que debo hacer, alguien podria orientarme?, les agradezco.

Tipo Informe de Excepción

mensaje No se puede compilar la clase para JSP:

Descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: No se puede compilar la clase para JSP:

Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: [10] en el archivo jsp: [/saludo.jsp]
java.util.date cannot be resolved to a type
7:
8: 
9:
10: La fecha del sistema es: <%= new java.util.date() %>
11: 
12:
13:

Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:528)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:400)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

nota La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos de registro del servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiene que ser `Date`, con D, no d.

```
new java.util.Date()
```

Comment: Ahora me siento como homero simpson, "debí parecer un estúpido!" , muchas gracias

Comment: Las preguntas que contienen "errores tipográficos" hay que marcarlas para cierre.

Comment: @jorgesys donde puedo leer de estas políticas? No que desconfíe de tu palabra, más bien x aprenderlas.

Comment: Hola @eftshift0, no te preocupes, cuando marcas a cierre, mira en las razones de cierre, uno de los puntos especifica : "Por que esta pregunta no es adecuada para Stack Overflow en español? Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos."